# ACL like matching in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I am trying to store ACL like data into a table and to check if a specific path is matching any of the stored pattern.

I tested on both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

There is my table and (BTREE) index:

```sql
create table acl (id serial, pattern text, block bool);
create index acl_pattern on acl(pattern);
```

I tried first to store wildcard like this, it works, but I could not find a way to use indexes, I don't think this is possible :

```
insert into acl values (default, '/public/%', false);
insert into acl values (default, '/admin/%', true);
select * from acl where '/public/hello' like pattern;
```

As most (if not all) the patterns will be prefixes only, I tried to avoid the wildcard by doing something like this, but I could not use indexes either:

```sql
insert into acl values (default, '/public/', false);
insert into acl values (default, '/admin/', true);

// PostgreSQL
test=# explain analyze select block from acl where pattern = substring('/public/blabla', 0, length(pattern)+1);
                                                   QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on acl  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000001.04 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=0.058..0.059 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (pattern = "substring"('/public/blabla'::text, 0, (length(pattern) + 1)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.074 ms
 Execution Time: 0.085 ms
(5 rows)

test=# explain analyze select block from acl where pattern = 'test';
                                                   QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using acl_pattern on acl  (cost=0.13..8.14 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (pattern = 'test'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.147 ms
 Execution Time: 1.063 ms
(4 rows)

// MySQL
mysql> explain select block from acl where pattern = left('/public/blabla', length(pattern));
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acl   | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select block from acl where pattern = "hello";
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acl   | NULL       | ref  | acl_pattern   | acl_pattern | 1019    | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

When I replace the right value of the comparison by a static value, indexes get used correctly, looks like either calling the function or using the pattern field on the right value invalidate the usage of indexes?

I also tried with CockroachDB for comparison (with the exact same queries than PostgreSQL) and I am getting exactly the same behaviour:

```sql
root@:26257/defaultdb> explain select block from acl where pattern = substring('/public/blabla', 0, length(pattern)+1);
    tree    | field  |                          description
+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
  render    |        |
   └── scan |        |
            | table  | acl@primary
            | spans  | ALL
            | filter | pattern = substring('/public/blabla', 0, length(pattern) + 1)

root@:26257/defaultdb> explain select block from acl where pattern = 'hello';
       tree       | field |         description
+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------+
  render          |       |
   └── index-join |       |
        ├── scan  |       |
        │         | table | acl@acl_pattern
        │         | spans | /"hello"-/"hello"/PrefixEnd
        └── scan  |       |
                  | table | acl@primary
```

Comment: Index won't be used for a single row. Populate the table with several thousand rows and run explain again.

Comment: Then why are they used correctly when I use `pattern = 'hello'` ?

Comment: You can not draw any conclusions from the tests on a one-row table.

Comment: I redid the same test with 100.000 rows (and running analyze) in the PostgreSQL table, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the index cannot be used because the right-hand expression depends on `pattern` (so needs a read from the table).

Assuming that you can determine the minimum length of the patterns (say 6 chars), you can try something like this:

```
create index acl_pattern on acl(left(pattern, 6));

select * 
from acl 
where left(pattern, 6) = left('/public/something', 6) and '/public/something' like pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

To use LIKE your index is missing the text_pattern_ops operator. Postgres is a little bit special when it comes to characters and the way it handles btrees means that behaviour will be different depending on the setting so you may need to read up on this. TLDR your index should look like this to use LIKE:

`create index acl_pattern on acl(pattern text_pattern_ops);`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-opclass.html

The other issue is that Postgres has a query planner, so if your table has only 2 rows, it wouldn't consider checking the index first cost worthy since the chances are the index would simply tell it to refer to the page on the table that both of these rows are on anyway.

Comment: I have put 100.000 on the table to have more data, but even after replacing my index by yours I am getting the same behaviour.

Comment: The tip is false. The index cannot support a column used on the right side of `like`.

Comment: My apologies, I did not see the query using like with the column value - the percent will be taken literally and not as a wildcard in this case

Answer (score 0):

(From a MySQL point of view.  I don't speak postgres.)

```
pattern = left('/public/blabla', length(pattern))
```

-->

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE pattern <= '/public/blabla'
    ORDER BY pattern DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

That will get you the first matching row in O(1) time.  Or it will give you something that does not match.  Now, let's check which:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT --- as above ) AS x
    WHERE pattern = LEFT('/public/blabla', CHAR_LENGTH(pattern))
```

This will either deliver the 1 row or the emptyset.